# What's the difference between `-new` and `-newkey` of `openssl req`?

Tags: openssl

I try to create selfsign-certificate with `openssl`. When create certificate request, I read the man page and confused about option `-new` and `-newkey`.

> -new    Generate a new certificate request.The user is prompted for the relevant field values. The actual fields prompted for and their maximum and minimum sizes are specified in the configuration file and any requested extensions.
>
> If the -key option is not used, it will generate a new RSA private key using information specified in the configuration file.

.

> -newkey arg
>   Create a new certificate request and a new private key.  The argument takes one of several forms.
>
> ...(some argument)

One is `Generate a new certificate request` and one is `Create a new certificate request`, I know the difference between `Generate` and `Create` , but can't understand the sentences :(

I tried `openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 ...` without `-new` as if there is no problem. But many documention is `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 ...` usually.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that -newkey creates a new private key as well, not just the certificate request.

```
-new Generate a new certificate request.
-newkey arg Create a new certificate request **and a new private key.**
```

If you use -new alone without -newkey but you omit -key (meaning that you don't specify what key you are using) then I believe it will be treated the same as -newkey and it will create a new private key too along with the certificate request.